# How to scan the input?

Tags: python, input

The question is basically if the two character code that the user enters only has letters then message should next include exactly those two letters.
 If the the two character code that the user enters has some digit or special symbol then the message being constructed should only attach the first character.

For example:

```
 > test = "stack overflow"
    > character = raw_input (Please provide a two character code with any
    > combination of letters, symbol or numbers: )
    character = "AA"
    message = "stack overflowAA"

    But IF 

    character = "6k"
    message = "stack overflow6"
```

Anyone have any idea how to do this?

Comment: You need to at least make an effort to build a functional program before people are going to help you.

Comment: go through tutorials first then if you have questions ask here. Don't just paste your homework questions. For tutorials start at https://wiki.python.org/moin/BeginnersGuide

Answer (score 0):

I would use string indexing to grab the first character and check if it is a digit with `.isdigit()`

```
sample_input = '6k'

# Get the first character from the input string
first_character = sample_string[0]

# Check if the first character is a digit
first_char_is_digit = first_character.isdigit()

# Choose how much of the input we want to use
if first_char_is_digit:
    my_suffix = first_character

else:
    my_suffix = sample_input

# Format our text, inserting our siffix in place of the `%s` placeholder
my_text = 'stackoverflow%s' % my_suffix

# Display text value
print(my_text)
```

I wrote it out as long as I could because your question is very basic, and I want to make the steps as obvious as possible. If I were writing this I would condense it like so:

```
sample_input = '6k'

if sample_string[0].isdigit():
    sample_input = sample_input[0]

print('stackoverflow%s' % sample_input)
```